# requires the services of

Tags: collocations, to-infinitive

Does the following make sense in a want ad?

Our company **requires** the services of a graphic artist **to work** in our Tokyo office.

Normally we require a person to do something. The sentence doesn't seem to follow this pattern.

Comment: They're called ***wanted** ads*, not *want ads*. But you're "over-analysing" the acceptability of ***to work*** there. Native speakers wouldn't see anything wrong with your example ***unless*** they were told there was definitely something wrong with the sentence (but even then I doubt they'd all identify that specific aspect of the text as being where the supposed fault lay).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - In the NYC area, I ___NEVER___ hear them called "wanted ads"; they're universally "want ads". In the newspaper, the page title is usually "Classified", with the specific type of ad being under the header "Help Wanted".

Comment: @Jeff: I'm surprised. According to Google Books there are a couple of hundred written instances for ***each*** of the 4 permutations ***post/posted** a **want/wanted** ad*, but they're not sufficiently common to check that extended context in NGrams for a UK/US usage split. On the other hand, if I just search for [a want ad,a wanted ad](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=posted+a+wanted+ad%2Cposted+a+want+ad&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) in NGrams, it would seem the version I know best barely exists at all, on the "global" scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the issue of want-ads...

The following is not an uncommon (if awkward) construction, and I've punctuated it the way I think it should be parsed:

> Our company requires the services of a graphic artist— to work in our
>   Tokyo office.

The infinitive clause **to work in our Tokyo office** is not a complement of **requires**:

`require {someone} {to do something}`

but should be understood as a *disjunct* addendum that adds some pertinent info about where this graphic artist would be working.

You also see the participle there serving the same purpose:

> Our company requires the services of a graphic artist— working in our
>   Tokyo office.

Comment: Can it be analyzed as "require the services of a graphic artist (who will be assigned) to work in our Tokyo office?

Comment: It amounts to much the same thing on a semantic level, but I don't think it's a relative clause.

Comment: If it isn't an infinitive phrase that functions as a relative but a detached modifier, wouldn't it be a dangling modifier?

Comment: As a clause without a crystal clear relationship to the main clause it does have things in common with the so-called "dangling modifier". Is it subject-oriented, expressing a need of **our company**? Does it express a condition pertinent to **the services of a graphic artist**?   Or does it do *both*? Perhaps it is dangling by two threads?

Answer (score 2):

No, the sentence seems to be a combination of:

> Our company requires the services of a graphic artist.

and

> Our company requires the graphic artist to work in our Tokyo office.

As it is written now it reads like you require the **services** to work in Tokyo. Better make it two sentences or rewrite it slightly. Examples:

> Our company requires the services of a graphic artist.
>   (S)he is required to work in our Tokyo office.

or:

> Our company requires the services of a graphic artist; (s)he will (have to) work in our Tokyo office.

or:

> Our company requires the services of a graphic artist, working in/from our Tokyo office.

Comment: While your analysis isn't wrong, it doesn't actually reflect the real-world usage; help-wanted advertisements in newspapers and industry journals often charge by the word, so minimizing the number of words becomes important. In the real world, the querent's construction is ***ubiquitous***, not merely common; I would be surprised to see any of your more-verbose alternatives.

Comment: +1. If you're looking to save a few yen: "Tokyo office needs graphic artist".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I missed the 'ad' part actually, just noticed the sentence not flowing well.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - if he's looking to save a few _yen_, he'd likely be writing in Japanese, rather than English.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly OK. You aren't specifying the specific duties of the graphic artist, so it is implied that the graphic artist will do all the normal things a graphic artist does, but will do so in and under the direction of the Tokyo office. This construction is quite common, and serves to screen out applicants for the job who would not be willing to relocate to the work location.